# Unable to test .then() part of modal in service - AngularJS unit test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

What I need is to catch .then part of closing or canceling modal in service function. With approach below that I am using for modal (with FakeModal function) everything is working in controller but how can I use this to test in service?

**Service**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

function reviewDeletionService($uibModal, $state, $rootScope, RecordLockService, $q, Restangular) {

    return {
        openDeletionModal:  openDeletionModal
    };


    function  openDeletionModal(reviewDetails, reviewImpacts, unlock) {
        var reviewDeletionModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            size: 'md',
            templateUrl: "src/app/common/modals/delete-review/deleteReviewImpacts.modal.view.html",
            backdrop: 'static',
            controller: 'DeleteReviewImpactsModalController as drivm',
            resolve: {
                reviewType: function () {
                    return reviewDetails.reviewType;
                },
                reviewTitle: function () {
                    return reviewDetails.reviewTitle;
                },
                reviewImpacts: function () {
                    return reviewImpacts;
                }
            }
        });

        reviewDeletionModalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
            openReviewReasonModal(reviewDetails, reviewImpacts, data.noImpacts, unlock);
        }, function () {
        if(unlock){
            RecordLockService.unlockReview(reviewDetails.reviewId);
        }                         
        })
    }
}

angular.module('common')
    .factory('ReviewDeletionService', reviewDeletionService);

})();
```

**TEST**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

describe("Service: ReviewDeletionService", function() {
    var reviewDeletionService, $httpBackend, restangular, successHandler, errorHandler, mockAuthenticationService, q, configParams ;
    var mockCurrentUser = {id: 1782, name: "One, Coordinator", roleId: [3, 10], eauthId: "coodinator1"};
    var recordLockService, modal, actualOptions;
    var fakeModal = {
        result: {
            then: function(confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
                //Store the callbacks for later when the user clicks on the OK button of the dialog
                this.confirmCallBack = confirmCallback;
                this.cancelCallback = cancelCallback;
            }
        },
        close: function( item ) {
            //The user clicked OK on the modal dialog, call the stored confirm callback with the selected item
            this.result.confirmCallBack(item);
        },
        dismiss: function( type ) {
            //The user clicked cancel on the modal dialog, call the stored cancel callback
            this.result.cancelCallback( type );
        }

    };

    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(module('common'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(_ReviewDeletionService_, _RecordLockService_, _$httpBackend_, _Restangular_, _AuthenticationService_, $q, _configParams_, _$uibModal_) {
        reviewDeletionService = _ReviewDeletionService_;
        recordLockService = _RecordLockService_;
        restangular = _Restangular_;
        q = $q;
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        modal = _$uibModal_;
        mockAuthenticationService = _AuthenticationService_;
        configParams = _configParams_;

        spyOn(mockAuthenticationService , 'getLoggedUser').and.callFake(function() {
            var deferred = q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(mockCurrentUser);
            return deferred.promise;

        });

        successHandler = jasmine.createSpy('success');
        errorHandler = jasmine.createSpy('error');
    }));
    afterEach(function() {
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
        $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });

    describe('call openDeletionModal function',function(){
        beforeEach(function () {
           spyOn(modal, 'open').and.callFake(function(options){
                actualOptions = options;
                return fakeModal;
            });
        }); 
        it('should call openDeletionModal', function() {
            reviewDeletionService.openDeletionModal(review, impacts, false);

         // Here I want to test.then part, I want my test to go inside .then part. 
         // If this was controller I would have just add
         //scope.lockedReviewModalInstance.close(data);
         // or. controller.lockedReviewModalInstance.close(data);

        });
    });

});
})();
```